# HTTP Error 401.2 Unthorized

Tags: asp.net

[image]

When I run my asp.net web application on the browser,it is showing this display scrren and ask me to enter user name and password. But i don't have any user name or password.

After i clicked cancel button, it shows this error message screen. I really have no idea to solve this problem.Please help me someone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are running in localhost or  what ?

Comment: In that case it must return a `Www-Authenticate` chalange header in response.That you'll send request back with a `Authorization` header.

Comment: yea..I'm running on localhost.  I tried lots of ways but still cannot solve this problem.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably need configure Authotization permissions/roles on your web.config or on your controller.